# Why do these probabilities not sum to 1?

Tags: probability

The problem involves me owning 2 black cows (B), 3 white cows (W), and 1 mixed cow (M) that is black on one side and white on the other.

I look out my window and see two cows standing with black sides facing me - the event bb.
The probability of the cows being one black and one mixed - the event MB - is:

---- note: P(BB) = (2C2)/(6C2) = 1/15, and P(MB) = (1C1)(2C1)/(6C2) = 2/15 ----

P(MB|bb) = P(bb|MB)P(MB)/[P(bb|MB)P(MB) + P(bb|BB)P(BB)]

P(MB|bb) = (1/2)(2/15)/[(1/2)(2/15) + (1)(1/15)] = 1/2

The only other possibility, when bb is given, is BB (that the two cows are black), but:

P(BB|bb) = P(bb|BB)P(BB)/[P(bb|BB)P(BB) + P(bb|MB)P(MB)]

P(BB|bb) = (1)(1/15)/[(1)(1/15) + (1/2)(2/15)] = 1/4

What event is related to the remaining 1/4?

EDIT: They don't sum to 1 because I can't count. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Check your arithmetic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 8 ways to get the cow to be black. 4 ways to get the two black cows in any of the sides.

The other 4 ways are determined by getting the mixed cow in the right position picking which of the black cows gets in and which of the black sides of the black cow is shown.

Comment: But are these equally likely events? The OP seems to be taking into account the two (equally likely) possible ways the mixed cow can be facing.

Comment: Not sure if that works since that sample space of 3 elements doesn't contain equally likely outcomes. Isn't the sample space we need to consider that of all the pairs of cows, with an additional factor for which way the black cows are oriented? So that sample space has 8 elements: 4 ways of pairing the black cows with each other, and 4 ways of pairing them with the mixed cow (which can only be oriented 1 way for bb to be true).

Comment: Does this help you now?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I understand the reasoning now, just not why the above calculation differs from this.

Comment: @Cam: As I said, check your arithmetic ... in the second calculation. Note the two probabilities are equal because $1/2\cdot 2=1$.

Comment: Oops, missed that. Thanks! Silly mistake helped me understand this problem more than I would have.